# How can I cast this into a graph algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of nodes A and a set of nodes B, where each node in A are connected to only one node in B. Now I want to select a minimum set of nodes in A that is connected to every nodes in B, while every selected node cannot be connected to each other.

I believe there is a certain way of solving this problem maybe with matching, independent set or whatever.

Comment: A and B form a bipartite graph?

Comment: @loganrakai The selected set of nodes from A and B forms a bipartite, while there are certain edges within A.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't been able to prove that my algorithm is correct, I'm still putting it here.

If the nodes in A didn't have edges between them, then this would be a bipartite graph matching problem. Right now this has become a bipartite graph matching problem with the constraint the if some node in A is selected, it may disqualify some other nodes in A.

For ease of visualisation, imagine the set of A on one sides and B on the other side, similar to the visuals drawn for Bipartite matching. Now, add another set of nodes C between A and B. The condition for adding a node in C are as follows:

- If there is a node in A (say `a`) with no edges in A, create a new node in C (say `c`), join `a` to `c`, and join all the corresponding nodes of `a` in B to `c`.
- If there are two nodes in A (`a1` and `a2`) which share an edge, create a new node in C (`c`) and create edges from `a1` to `c`, `a2` to `c`, and from `c` to all corresponding nodes in B.

Now we can use the Max-Flow algorithm to get the desired output. We should set the node capacities of each node in C to be 1 (the way to achieve this is by creating another intermediate layer D which is a copy of C, with edge capacities equal to 1 for edges between C and D)

Any help in making the proof rigorous or any counter examples would be helpful.